# How to add new html5 like buttons in website

Tags: facebook, html, facebook-like

I'm relatively new to this and looking to implement like buttons for videos and articles on a website. I would prefer to get the better functionality from the html5 option over the iframe option. Not sure what I need to do as far as creating the app, getting app ID, and what I need to add to the site from the SDK in addition to the HTML5 code generated on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ when I put in all the info.

Is there a step by step guide somewhere that I can follow to implement this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Here's [Facebook's Open Graph protocol](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/). There's a **Getting Started** section with all of the info you need. Just follow the instructions and your site should work fine.